# Send notifications to user authorised to facebook in mobile for different events

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-page

Logic/Code question here.

Hello all,
 I am building an social network type of Android app where specific group of people share their views. And for this , I planned to use only Facebook for everything, posting, commenting and all. The posts are posted on a page.

My problem is like this:
Suppose, a user posted a thing through the app, another user comes and interact with the post by commenting.

Now I need to send a notification to the first user that second user interacted with his/her post.

The notification should be on mobile app, not Facebook app.

Any idea, how can I solve this problem? 
Any sort of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple solution for this. You may want to look for third-party solutions. Basically,

- When a user logs in, send the device token and facebook user id to your server and store them in a database.
- When a user makes a post, link the post id to the device token.
- When a user comments, get the facebook user id of the parent post, then get the device token, then send a notification to the device token.

Comment: Thanks for the re reply.. this could be a solution. But if no other solution can't be found, then it would be better not to use facebook for this. I think.